# Mark rpm package as automatically installed

Tags: rpm, repository

On debian systems I can use `aptitude markauto` and `aptitude unmarkauto` to mark packages as manually or automatically installed. I use this to remove unneeded packages by marking the packages I know I want. Then `apt-get autoremove` will remove all packages that are not needed.

I'm now on a fedora system and would like a similar feature in either rpm or yum or other program. Does rpm/yum even have a concept of manual/auto installed packages like debian systems?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At least newer yum versions (tested on Fedora 20 with yum 3.4.3) are able to distinguish between manually-installed packages and packages installed as dependencies. This information is stored in yumdb using the key "reason" which can be either set to "user" or "dep".

```
# yumdb set reason dep [package name or wildcard]
```

should be the equivalent to "aptitude markauto". If you do not provide a package name, the change is applied to all packages. I wouldn't do that, the less radical way is to use

```
# yumdb search reason user
```

and manually remove the packages you don't want.

If you run

```
# yum autoremove
```

all packages marked as "dep" are removed if they are no longer referenced by other packages. Should be equivalent to "aptitude autoremove".

Packages installed not using yum (e.g rpm -i) might not have the "reason" key, I assume the default behavior of autoremove is to treat them as "user" packages, but they are not listed using the "yumdb search" command.

Comment: For future reference on newer systems, the `dnf` equivalents of the above commands are: `dnf mark install [package names]` to mark packages as user-installed; `dnf mark remove [package names]` to mark packages as installed for dependencies; and `dnf autoremove` to remove dependency-installed packages that are no longer needed.

Comment: To list user installed packages: `dnf repoquery --userinstalled`

Answer (score 5):

## With DNF

To unmark a package as user installed (ie. the package will be removed by autoremove if it is not a dependency of a user installed package):

```
dnf mark remove [package name or wildcard]
```

Conversely, to mark a package as user installed (the package will never be removed by autoremove):

```
dnf mark install [package name or wildcard]
```

There is also `dnf mark group [package]`, which marks a package as having been installed as part of some package group. When a package is marked as installed by a group it will be removed when any group it belongs to is removed using the `dnf group remove` command **if** it is not part of another installed group.

Answer (score 0):

No, but there's no reason one couldn't write a yum plugin to provide this ability.

Comment: So yum/rpm has no concept of manual/auto package states? Just installed/not installed?

Comment: Correct. There's a plugin for removing leaves, but that's not quite the same thing.